# Homotopical characterization of manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metrizable topological space of covering dimension $4$.

Assume that for any point $x\in X$ any neighbourhood of $x$ contains a contractible open neighbourhood $U$ such that $U\setminus\{x\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^3$.

Is $X$ a manifold?

Comment: Does the assumption imply that $X$ has the disjoint disks property? If not, maybe that could be used to construct a counterexample?

Comment: Why do you restrict to dimension 4? This needs motivation. Have you heard of [Bing's dogbone space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogbone_space)? I believe that an analogue exists in all dimensions $n\geqslant3$. Is the point to rule them out? Have you heard of ANR homology manifolds? (a lousy name that cannot be decomposed into its component parts, but which can be googled) These are very subtle examples that you cannot rule out without very subtle hypotheses. Is the point to ask if they exist in dimension 4?